# Can the apps that are integrate with the classroom run from any server?

Tags: google-classroom

If i integrate my app with the class room where it will be.Is it must in the google cloud server or it can run from any server.

Comment: [Classroom API is just a RESTful interface](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started). As long as you know how to make the [authorized requests](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth), you should be fine.

Comment: I am using server to server authentication to get data from google classroom, 

but getting this error PERMISSION_DENIED, could you please help, I could share my code if needed